# DownloadManager not adding the file extension

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I would like to download from my server *.apk file, the file type on the server is *.apk and the MIME is application/vnd.android.package-archive",
when downloading with the DownloadManager the file is downloaded but it creating it without the extension "apk", I tried this

```
request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

and still no luck the file created without the extension,
when trying to download it with **Chrome** it worked perfectly...

please help.

Comment: Are you trying to using any of the setDestination methods on your request?

Comment: You might want to share an answer to the problem just incase anyone else falls into the same trap :)

Answer (score 2):

I thought request.setMimeType(..) is used it will add the file extension automatically or Android will recognize the file type,but no... you need to use setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(...)
and set the file extension here....